# How to determine position of XMLNode in an XML document?

Tags: xml, delphi, xml-parsing, delphi-xe2, msxml

I'm using `TXMLDocument` to parse an XML document (either from file, or from memory), and display it in a tree view. Is there any way to get the character position and length of an `XMLNode` in the XML content? I want to highlight the node text in the original document, either when the user selects its equivalent node in the tree, or when there is something odd about that node, like empty value, wrong text, etc.

I read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/e3x60fe9.aspx), but I'm not sure how to implement it in Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

The only class that can provide this information is XML parser. I don't know if TXMLDocument does so (I couldn't find anything). But there might be a problem with exact position in file. Generally an XML document can be a dirty file and need some formatting to show. If so the problem changes to determine position of node after formatting. It's  a little easier to do, because you can use same data (IXMLNode) to both fill the tree and show formatted XML.

I used `FormatXMLData` to display XML in a RichEdit, and used `DomToTree` from [here](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/master-delphi-7/content/LiB0209.html) to fill up the tree. I changed `DomToTree` to keep the line index of each node. It came out like this:

```
procedure TForm1.DomToTree (XmlNode: IXMLNode; TreeNode: TTreeNode;
  var CurrentLineIndex: Integer); // <--- added this parameter
var
  I: Integer;
  NewTreeNode: TTreeNode;
  NodeText: string;
  AttrNode: IXMLNode;
begin
  // skip text nodes and other special cases
  if XmlNode.NodeType <> ntElement then
    Exit;
  // add the node itself
  NodeText := XmlNode.NodeName;
  if XmlNode.IsTextElement then
    NodeText := NodeText + '=' + XmlNode.NodeValue;
  NewTreeNode := TreeView1.Items.AddChildObject(TreeNode, NodeText, Pointer(CurrentLineIndex));
  // add attributes
  for I := 0 to xmlNode.AttributeNodes.Count - 1 do
  begin
    AttrNode := xmlNode.AttributeNodes.Nodes[I];
    TreeView1.Items.AddChildObject(NewTreeNode,
      '[' + AttrNode.NodeName + '="' + AttrNode.Text + '"]', Pointer(CurrentLineIndex));
  end;
  Inc(CurrentLineIndex);
  // add each child node
  if XmlNode.HasChildNodes then
  begin
    for I := 0 to xmlNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
    begin
      DomToTree (xmlNode.ChildNodes.Nodes[I], NewTreeNode, CurrentLineIndex);
    end;
    Inc(CurrentLineIndex);
  end;
end;
```

Now I can highlight equivalent text of selected node in RichEdit:

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1Change(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
var
  LineIndex, TextPos: Integer;
  Text: string;
begin
  SetSelBgColor(RichEdit1, clWhite);
  LineIndex := Integer(Node.Data);
  TextPos := RichEdit1.Perform(EM_LINEINDEX, LineIndex, 0);
  Text := Node.Text;
  Text := ReplaceStr(Text, '[', '');
  Text := ReplaceStr(Text, ']', '');

  RichEdit1.SelStart := TextPos + Pos(Text, RichEdit1.Lines[LineIndex]) - 1;
  RichEdit1.SelLength := Length(Text);
  SetSelBgColor(RichEdit1, clYellow);
end;
```

And the whole thing starts like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FirstLineIndex: Integer;
begin
  with TOpenDialog.Create(Self) do
  begin
    if Execute then
    begin
      XMLDocument1.LoadFromFile(FileName);
      Treeview1.Items.Clear;
      FirstLineIndex := 1;
      DomToTree (XMLDocument1.DocumentElement, nil, FirstLineIndex);
      TreeView1.FullExpand;
      RichEdit1.Lines.Text := FormatXMLData(XMLDocument1.XML.Text);
    end;
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

But it's not an assured code as isn't expected to be, because `DomToTree` and `FormatXMLData` don't work properly together. I tested the code with some files and it failed in lots of them. The best approach would be to rewrite both of them. But if you want to test the code, it works with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DATAPACKET Version="2.0">
  <METADATA>
    <FIELDS>
      <FIELD attrname="ClientDataSet1FieldCode" fieldtype="i4"/>
      <FIELD attrname="ClientDataSet1FieldContact" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="50"/>
      <FIELD attrname="ClientDataSet1FieldNoTell" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="15"/>
    </FIELDS>
    <PARAMS CHANGE_LOG="1 0 4"/>
  </METADATA>
  <ROWDATA>
    <ROW RowState="4" ClientDataSet1FieldCode="1" ClientDataSet1FieldContact="Ali" ClientDataSet1FieldNoTell="012345678"/>
  </ROWDATA>
</DATAPACKET>
```